# Python animated cursor next to a printed line

Tags: python, linux

i am a hobbyist programmer and i make different programs in python which is my favorite.

I work on linux OS and i made a program that prints a text and then runs a subprocess.call :

```
for i in range(1,10):
   print("Running this command") #I want to put some animation here
   subprocess.call(["xterm", "-e", " < runs a command for x amount of time and exits> "])
```

As stated in the above code i want to include some animation like (/,|,\,|) etc to print on the same line as "Running this command" and when the subprocess.call window closes then i want the animation to stop so the loop can continue on the next line with the same concept as the above line
I found some examples on the site but i cant stop the animation , so the loop doesn't continues.

Thanks for your time !!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example I got. I am on Windows, so substitute the command for whatever you want.

```py
from itertools import cycle
from subprocess import Popen
from time import sleep

sequence = cycle(['|', '\\', '-', '/'])  # cycles through the symbols for you animation

proc = Popen(['notepad.exe']) # substitute for your command.

while proc.poll() == None: 
# If the process is open, proc.poll() returns None, so this checks if it 
# is still running
    print(f'\rRunning {next(sequence)}', end='') 
    # \r sets the line back at the beginning, end='' makes so that print doesn't add a 
    #newline at the end
    time.sleep(0.5) # Makes it so it doesn't spin so fast
```

Now you need to adapt this to your usecase. I would envelop the process creating and loop into a function and then call it on your other loop.